# Doctrine join table not reflecting

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have created two Doctrine Entity,Like below.

```
class Corporate {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

....
...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CorporateJobs", mappedBy="corporate", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     **/
    private $corporate_jobs;

}
```

and similrly corresponding ManytoOne relationship in CorporateJobs Entity Table.

```
class CorporateJobs {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Corporate")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="corporate_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     **/ 
    private $corporate;

}
```

While retrieving the value from Indexcontroller,
Its not taking entry for my corporateJobs table.

> array(22) { ["id"]=> int(6) ["prefix"]=> NULL ["first_name"]=>
>   string(8) "Mob" ["last_name"]=> string(1) "b" ["corporate_jobs"]=>
>   array(0) { } }

corporate_jobs table has fields like corporate_id jobtitle jobdescription location/
Corporate_id is mapped to user_id or corporate_id in corporate Entity.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Corporate")
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CorporateJobs")
```

The targetEntity requires the full namespace to the Entity, otherwise Doctrine isn't going to know any of the table mappings for the Corporate entity.